# How to make Gnome Shell Alt+Tab list applications before switching to the next one?

Tags: gnome-shell

I use Gnome Shell 3.4 and I find the Alt+Tab feature extremely powerful. Switching between opened application windows is fast and effective, at least more than trough the overview.

Unfortunately, I sometimes press Alt+Tab in order to list active windows before realizing I actually should stay on the current active window OR switch between windows on the current application. In that cases, I either

need to Alt+Tab all my way back
use the inconvenient Shift+Alt+Tab to go one item back
use my mouse to "manually" select the window I really want
All of this could be avoided if Alt+Tab would prompt a list of the active windows first, without automatically switching to the next application. Do you know any way to do that? Should I use something else instead?

Thanks in advance for you answers.